# Python Pyramid settings unavailable in registry

Tags: python, pyramid

According to the docs [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/environment.html), one can access settings in the .ini files for use throughout the application, even where there is no access to the request object.  I would find this very useful because I want to stipulate different database strings per .ini and have access to them not only at `__init__` but from elsewhere in the application.  However, whenever and wherever I try it, the value of `settings` is `None`.  Why?  (Pyramid v1.5.7)

```
registry = pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_registry()
settings = registry.settings
debug_frobnosticator = settings['debug_frobnosticator']
```

Here is the way the app is initialized:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from pyramid.security import authenticated_userid
from bang.model import RootFactory, groupFinder
from pyramid.renderers import JSON
import json
from datetime import datetime, date
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore
from pytz import utc
import platform
from bang.classes import *  # the db string is required in this module
import logging
from datetime import timedelta

# main app config
def main(global_config, **settings):
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
        secret='xxxxxx',
        callback=groupFinder,
        hashalg='sha512',
        include_ip=True,
        timeout=36000)
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config = Configurator(
        settings=settings,
        root_factory=RootFactory)
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)



    logging.getLogger("apscheduler.scheduler").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger("apscheduler.executors.default").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    ### first use of db from bang.classes here
    # set house_id auto_inc to the highest current house_id
    new_int = Asset().find().sort('house_id_int', -1)[0].house_id_int
    Asset()._database['Sequences'].find_and_modify({'_id': 'house_id_int'}, {'$set': {'seq': new_int}}, upsert=True)

    # set house_id auto_inc to the highest current house_id
    new_int = Contract().find().sort('code_int', -1)[0].code_int
    Contract()._database['Sequences'].find_and_modify({'_id': 'code_int'}, {'$set': {'seq': new_int}}, upsert=True)

    def get_user(request):
        user = User().find_one({'_id': ObjectId(authenticated_userid(request))}, fields={'password': False})
        return {'_id': user._id, 'defaults': user.defaults, 'full_name': user.full_name, 'first_name': user.first_name,
            'last_name': user.last_name, 'login_count': user.login_count, 'permissions': user.permissions}

    # if this Pyramid instance is an Agent host, then start a scheduler
    agent = Agent().find_one({'host_name': platform.node()})
    if agent:

        # created background scheduler
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(
            jobstores={
            'mongo': MongoDBJobStore(client=cn, database='foobar', collection='ScheduledJobs_%s' % agent.host_name, timezone=utc,
                                     job_defaults={'coalesce': True, 'misfire_grace_time': 86400})})
        log.info('created scheduler for agent_host %s' % agent.host_name)
        # start the scheduler
        scheduler.start()

        def get_scheduler(request):
            return scheduler
        config.add_request_method(get_scheduler, 'scheduler', reify=True)

    for agent in Agent().find({'host_name': platform.node()}):
        # add a job to scan the agent
        log.info('added scan schedule for %s on %s' % (agent.name, agent.host_name))
        scheduler.add_job(agent_scan, trigger='interval', args=[str(agent._id)], jobstore='mongo',
                      id='%s_scan' % agent._id, seconds=agent.scan_cycle, replace_existing=True)
        # add a job to process the agent's joblist
        log.info('added jobs schedule for %s on %s' % (agent.name, agent.host_name))
        scheduler.add_job(agent_jobs, trigger='interval', args=[str(agent._id)], jobstore='mongo',
                      id='%s_jobs' % agent._id, seconds=10, start_date=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=60), replace_existing=True)

    # add the authenticated user to each request
    config.add_request_method(get_user, 'user', reify=True)

    # custom json adapters
    custom_json = JSON()

    def haystack_obj_adapter(obj, request):
        return obj.json

    config.add_renderer('json', custom_json)

    # routes for standard static images
    config.add_route('apple-touch', '/apple-touch-icon.png')
    # etc

    # routes
    config.add_route('remote.files', '/remote/files/{method}')
    # etc

    config.add_static_view('/', 'static', cache_max_age=0)

    config.scan()

    return config.make_wsgi_app()


TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you show us how do you initialize the wsgi app?

Comment: @matino I've added the config for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code lacks full traceback and view code.

It actually doesn't work in a way you might expect. Thread-local might not be set, as this function is mostly designed for `pyramid.testing` and unit tests if I have understood correctly. The thread life cycle is different on normal requests and unit tests.

Please use `request.registry` in views and pass `registry` explicitly around. If you need to access `registry` in `main()` pass it around from `config.registry`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think a full traceback may be irrelevant in this case.  Essentially, the docs state that the current registry is available from anywhere within the app, and it is.  However, the settings are None.  I'm not sure what you mean by "pass it around from config.registry".

Comment: If you create objects during your application initialization stage (main()) you give the registry during the object construction

Comment: OK but in my case I want to pass the registry to an imported module.

Comment: Without seeing the code it is very hard to tell what you are trying to do or what would be the best approach here.

Comment: I understand.  I think I've figured out (with your help) that what I'm trying to do could only be done by manually reading the .ini file before the Pyramid app is initialized anyway.  Thanks for helping out

Comment: If you need to "initialize before initialized" checkout `pyramid.paster.bootstrap()` - e.g. used by Pyramid's own command line scripts

Comment: You can still poke into INI directly but that's not very clean... maybe the solution here is to change the initialization / Python import order so that you have registry available when you ramp up your objects.

Comment: Thanks, those last two comments are especially helpful. The bootstrapping sound very promising and it feels more like where this belongs